# MPEG DASH: playing fragment as soon (and as many times) as it's appended to SourceBuffer

Tags: javascript, html, mpeg-dash, media-source, mp4box

Is it possible to make HTML5 video tag playing fragments as soon and as many times as I append them to SourceBuffer? So that, for example, if I append fragment2 - I would like it to immediately play fragment2 even if there were no fragment1, and if I append fragment2 again - I would it to play fragment2 again.

I've already tried to pass MediaSource an initial segment + fragment2 without fragment1, but what I've found is that instead of immediately playing it it just fills up a corresponding part of timeline with it. So that if I seek to corresponding place - it will start playing it, but if I wouldn't - it will not (unless I also pass fragment1, ofk). To say nothing that even if I append fragment2 to SourceBuffer again, it will not automatically play it again until I seek.

Here is a way that I'm using to produce a MP4/DASH stream:

```
$ MP4Box -dash 30000 -dash-profile on-demand -segment-name output-seg output.mp4
$ cat output-seginit.mp4 output-seg2.m4s >test.mp4
```

Here is a corresponding HTML5/JavaScript code:

```
<audio id="player" controls></audio>

<script>
var player = document.querySelector("#player");
var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
player.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function() {
   console.log('sourceopen');
   var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"'); // My video only contains audio stream

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.onload = function(event) {
      console.log("appendBuffer");
      sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(event.target.response);
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'test.mp4');
    xhr.send(null);
});
</script>
```

Is it possible to do what I want? Also, it would be appreciated if somebody could suggest me a proper word how to call this - I'd refer it as "live streaming", but I'm not sure.